# Why is the + operator for List deprecated in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, operator-overloading, deprecated

Why is the + operator for List deprecated in Scala?

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/List.html#%2B%28B%29

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Good question, so I looked it up in the book by Odersky et al. It says the following (hopefully it's not a copyright infringement to quote this here ;-)):

---

### *Why not append to lists?*

*Class `List`does not offer an append operation because the time it takes to append to a list grows linearly with the size of the list, whereas prepending with `::` takes constant time. Your options if you want to build a list by appending elements is to prepend them, then when you're done call `reverse`; or use a `ListBuffer`, a mutable list that does offer an append operation, and when you're done call `toList`.*

---

As far as I understand FP, prepending to a list is much more common than appending, at least in pure functional languages. I can only assume that the designers of Scala added the `+` operator as a convenience for Java developers, who are used to appending using `add()`, and then had second thoughts about it.

Comment: Actually, that's not even really an FP thing, it's a general trait of how a persistent recursive linked list works: prepending is updating one single pointer/reference/whatever you want to call it, appending needs to copy the entire list. So, prepending is `O(1)` with a tiny constant factor, appending is `O(n)` with a rather hefty `c`.

Comment: Well, the `O(n)` complexity results from the need to copy the list, which results from the requirement of having immutable lists. And using only immutable data is a hallmark of functional programming languages. So I would still say it's an FP thing. In Java's list types, or e.g. `std::list::push_back` in C++ appending has `O(1)`.

Answer (score 14):

It was deprecated in May 2008 in [revision 15071](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/15071), with the message:

> Deprecate all of the problematic + methods, and removed those that never appeared in a release.

I expect this was to avoid ambiguity with StringAdd#+. Compare the difference between 2.7.6 an 2.8.0 Beta below:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.7.6.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_15).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> List(1) + 2
warning: there were deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> List(1) + "2"
warning: there were deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2)
```

In 2.8, the method has been removed and you get:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.Beta1-RC8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_15).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> List(1) + 2
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: String
       List(1) + 2
                 ^

scala> List(1) + "2"
res1: java.lang.String = List(1)2
```

**UPDATE**

On the scala-user list, Martin Odersky notes:

> To find out what's really bad about
>   List#+, consider what you would expect
>   the following to produce:
>
> List(1, 2, 3) + " is the correct
>   result"
>
> ?

**oxbow_lakes adds** - *it took me a while to unpack this cryptic comment but I think the point is that it would violate the commutativity of types implied by the `+` operator. That is, the type of `a + b` should be the same as the type of `b + a`*

**UPDATE**
Martin Odersky's clarification:

> What would you expect
>
> > List(1, 2, 3) + " is the correct result"
>
> to produce? I would expect a string:
>   "List(1, 2, 3) is the correct result".
>
> With 2.7 style List.+, you get instead
>   a List[Any], List(1, 2, 3, "is the
>   correct result").
>
> I classify that as a bad surprise. In
>   summary, one should never have a
>   + method on collections that are covariant in their element type. Sets
>   and maps are non-variant, that's why
>   they can have a + method. It's all
>   rather delicate and messy. We'd be
>   better off if we did not try to
>   duplicate Java's + for String
>   concatenation. But when Scala got
>   designed the idea was to keep
>   essentially all of Java's expression
>   syntax, including String +. And it's
>   too late to change that now.

Comment: While this kind of thing is a general problem of automatic type conversions. I don't understand, why the List.+ operator is the bad guy here. Actually the only result that confuses me is the last one.

Comment: Predef.anyToStringEquals is an unfortunate deference to Java compatibility. I agree it is confusing. Looking at the other posts, the deprecation seems not to be directly related to this, however.

Answer (score 12):

It was not commutative and was particularly suboptimal on lists. Furthermore, behavior differs between mutable and immutable collections. On Scala 2.8, you have the following:

```
element +: sequence   // prepend
sequence :+ element   // append
sequenece ++ sequence // concatenate
```

The mutable/immutable thing is not quite solved. A bunch of methods were deprecated as a first step, but they can't be changed or outright removed without a deprecation period first.

Comment: None of those operators are commutative either.  In fact, collections operators seldom are.

Comment: Yeah, but `+:` and `:+` are not well known operators that people expect to be commutative.

Comment: This is what I searched for! As a java developer and scala beginner all the fancy operators are making me insane...

Answer (score 3):

If you follow [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/adding-elements-to-end-of-a-List-td17688770.html), you will see it is probably for performance issue.

> Generally one should arrange `List` construction so as to not append. 
>   Scala's List is an immutable single linked list, so appending to the end of it is an O(n) operation.
>
> `ListA ::: ListB` is right-associative, and runs in time proportional to the length of ListA 
>   '`a ::: b`' is a /prepend/ operation, which runs in `O(a.length)` time