# + Operator on lists in Scala

Tags: list, scala, collections

I'm pretty new to Scala programming and now trying to understand the exact behavior of the operator `+` for the [scala.collection.immutable.List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). Here is what I wrote:

```
val _1 = List(1, 2)
println((_1 + "2") foreach print
```

I couldn't write the following

```
_1 + 2 //error: expected String
```

That's clear, because we're trying to execute the `+` operator defined within the `String` class.

But what is not clear it's why they didn't just override the `operator +` for the `List`, but instead defined `operator ++` for concatenating?

Was there some technical reason for that?

What does that mean?

Comment: I think it is a design flaw of the Scala authors to make `+` attached to `String`s.

Comment: What do you mean by "operator + for the List"? scala.ollection.immutable.List does not provide the `+` operator. And what you want would be `:+` instead of `+` or `++`.

Comment: @yanana I know. That's exactly what I was confused by. What was the reason for not providing an overriden version for List?

Comment: There is a `+` for everything convertible to `String`. So the `List` is first converted to `String` and then there is a `+` operator.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465753/what-scala-feature-allows-the-plus-operator-to-be-used-on-any

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123290/why-is-the-operator-for-list-deprecated-in-scala

Comment: IMHO, to provide a `+` operator to the `List`-like data structure is just a bad habit as the `+` operation in mathematics is commutative, but `List` nor even `String` is not.

Comment: You can build with `-Yno-predef` to avoid the confusing conversion that adds a string-based `+` operator.

Answer (score 2):

> why they didn't just override the operator + for the List, but instead defined operator ++ for concatenating?

Methods that take not individual elements but collections usually indicate that by a "plural" operator, e.g. `++` to concatenate collections, `:::` to prepend lists. The `+` method is for example used to add individual elements to non-linear collections `Set` and `Map`:

```
Set(1, 2, 3) + 4
Map(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar") + (3 -> "baz")
```

And in "plural":

```
Set(1, 2, 3) ++ Set(4, 5, 6)
```

Linear collections indicate the "direction" by adding a colon, so `:+` for append and `+:` for prepend:

```
1 +: Seq(2, 3) :+ 4
```

> Was there some technical reason for that?

No. It is possible to define the `+` method on any type for any reason. It is just not advised.

---

```
List(1, 2) + "3" // "List(1, 2)3"
```

This is a common puzzler in Scala. If the right hand operand is a `String`, there is an implicit conversion of the left operand to another `String` using the `toString` method, glueing the two strings together.